# Android App Optimization avoiding OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-mapview, tiles

I have an Android 13mb application, which displays offline/cached map  from sd card. I am using mapnik mapsource, and has 33, 000 map tiles.

```
 m_mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
```

Problem:

When viewing the map, it takes time to load the maptiles. Furthermore, when scrolling it will freeze for about 2-3 seconds, then it will force closed. Can I use try catch?

[image]

Comment: Please use the text from logcat instead of images

Comment: I cannot copy the lagcat details sir, so I print screen it

Comment: You can, actually... select the lines you want to copy then do `Control + C`, or go to `Edit -> Copy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these images are large or many, then you may simply not have enough memory to keep them all in memory at once. You will have to find a way to intelligently load and unload the tiles to fit into available heap space, which is 32MB.

However, I have another guess: are you calling `recycle()` on the `Bitmap` objects that you do not need anymore? if you don't you can quickly get this error, even when there is enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly the tiles are displayed but some points here anyway:

1. Make sure you are keeping things in memory only if you need them. The Android heap size varies between 16-32MB and when it runs out which it often does, your app will crash.
2. Use WeakReferences - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html
3. As you are loading things from the SD card every time things will be slow. Make sure you are doing this on a separate thread.
4. If possible, use the NDK. Native code doesn't have the strict requirements which the Java environment on Android imposes.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, I don't know how to code in such a way that I keep things in Memory. Second, can you give an example when sir on when to do threading. Third, I a new to java and I have no idea how to use File I/O, can you give other items aside from file I/O... Thank you sir and more power